# WiX: Powershell variables in XML commands

Tags: xml, variables, powershell, wix

I'm trying to create some XML where I'm creating the directory structure with XML Commands.  The directory depth (As shown below) is variable.

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="PFiles" />
   <Directory Id="subdir1" Name="subdir1">
     <Directory Id="subdir2" Name="subdir2">
       <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="$(var.Directory)">
```

The Powershell function code is like this.  I pass in three variables, $Id, $Name, and an INT $i.  $XMLNS is defined at $script: level.

```
function WriteDirectory {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$Id,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$Name,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][int]$NumDirectories
        )
    $Directories = $null
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $NumDirectories; $i++) {
        $Directories += "Directory."
    }
    # Trim the trailing dot
    [string]$Directories = $Directories.SubString(0,$Directories.Length-1)
    $NewDirectory = $XML.CreateElement('Directory', $XMLNS)
    $NewDirectory.SetAttribute('Id', $Id)
    $NewDirectory.SetAttribute('Name', $Name)
    $XML.Wix.Product.$Directories.AppendChild($NewDirectory) # This is the problem code
}
```

Powershell doesn't like strings as part of an object.  $i could be as high as 7, so the last command would essentially be, if $i were 7:

```
$XML.Wix.Product.Directory.Directory.Directory.Directory.Directory.Directory.Directory.AppendChild($NewDirectory)
```

How can I easily form that last XML command that is essentially dynamic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a recursive function. You could decrement `$NumDirectories` with each recursive call if you have a fixed depth:

```
function AppendDirectory {
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]$parentNode,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$Id,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$Name,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][int]$NumDirectories
  )

  if ($NumDirectories -eq 0) {
    $NewDirectory = $xml.CreateElement('Directory')
    $NewDirectory.SetAttribute('Id', $Id)
    $NewDirectory.SetAttribute('Name', $Name)
    $parentNode.AppendChild($NewDirectory)
  } else {
    AppendDirectory $parentNode.Directory $Id $Name ($NumDirectories - 1)
  }
}

AppendDirectory $XML.Wix.Product 'Id' 'Name' 5
```

Or, if you want to append a new `Directory` node at the leaf `Directory` node regardless of depth, you could do something like this:

```
function AppendDirectory {
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]$parentNode,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$Id,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$Name
  )

  if ($parentNode.ChildNodes.Count -eq 0) {
    $NewDirectory = $xml.CreateElement('Directory')
    $NewDirectory.SetAttribute('Id', $Id)
    $NewDirectory.SetAttribute('Name', $Name)
    $parentNode.AppendChild($NewDirectory)
  } else {
    AppendDirectory $parentNode.Directory $Id $Name
  }
}

AppendDirectory $XML.Wix.Product 'Id' 'Name'
```

Comment: This worked great!  I had tried something similar to your top choice, but I was way off and couldn't get it to work.  Thanks much!